# Import PycURL to report an error in macOS

Tags: python

Used `pip install pycurl`to install with success,but importing pycurl report an error.

searched for more details for error `from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)`, but this problem is `libcurl link-time ssl backend (none/other)`

I don't know how to solve it.

Environment:

- macOS 10.11.6
- brew install openssl(latest)

  ```
  import pycurl
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (none/other) is different from compile-time ssl backend (openssl)
  ```

Comment: Looking for some answers to my system version reason.
Upgrade to MAC OS 11.13 High Sierra can be solved

Comment: I upgraded the macOS from 10.11.6(El Capitan ) to 10.14(Mojave) to solve this problem.